# Curious translate+overflow bug in IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, css, transform

In IE10 (Windows 8 and only Windows 8, including RT), I have this `div` with a `overflow : auto` which is animated from outside the screen (CSS3 `transition` + `transform`)

The content of this `div` (plain text) is not rendered until the end of the transition, ie the `div` seems empty.

If I set `overflow : hidden`, the problem disappear.

This behavior is reproduced here : http://jsbin.com/inUsayU/5/
(this jsBin link will only work in IE10)

Keep the screen splitted (if not splitted, add a CSS and a HTML pane), hover the first link, you should see the `div` transitionning empty. Try hovering the second link, the other `div` transition fine. You may have to restart with "Run with JS" each time, because often (not always) the problem is only happening once.

On my project, I hacked an ugly solution with UA Sniffing and switching the `overflow` state before and after the transition, but I hope there's a simpler explanation/solution you can provide.

Comment: 1) A "fiddle" implies you have used http://jsfiddle.net 2) You refer to the *second link*, but in your jsbin demo there is only one link. 3) When I hover the link in Windows 7 IE10 the `div` slides across the screen and does not appear empty.

Comment: 1/ don't care. 2/ oups, did not link the good fiddle. 3/ you should. Use the splitted screen in edit mode + run with JS button, the bug is more obvious then. It's not systematic, so try several times.

Comment: I am still not seeing the issue on Windows 7 - IE10. Both links work the same for me.

Comment: I'll boot a VM to check on W7. I have this bug on both surface (pro & RT) and on a W8 desktop.

Comment: Well, sir, you are absolutely correct : this bug does not happen on IE10/W7.

Comment: Yes spotted the same. Dunno maybe a scrollbar issue or could be anything. Will update if i find something

Comment: this is probably a bug with them.... most ppl probably wont know about some obsolete bug, and a efficient fix, just hope users dont use w8/ie10 or just use ur fix.

Comment: Can you wrap the scrolling `div` in a container and move the `transition`/`transform` styles to the container?

Comment: If I remember correctly, it won't work. Not 100% sure though, I'll have to test this sometimes.

Comment: I tested your demo in IE11 on Windows 8.1 and do not see anything wrong. Seems to be working fine for me. I also emulated IE10 and there was still no adverse effect. If this was indeed an issue with IE10, it won't be an issue long as IE10 users are auto-updated to IE11.

Answer (score 1):

I tested in this Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8.1. I also tested with IE10 Emulation enabled. Further, I tested in IE10 on Windows Phone. This is in addition to the IE10 tests conducted on Windows 7 already. In all cases, I did **not** see the issue you reported. I suspect there was something else to this other than a bug with the browser.

With regards to your implementation, I would suggest avoiding `-ms-transition` as prefixed properties are considered to be experimental. [Internet Explorer 10 supports the unprefixed transition property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I'm currently downloading an IE10 Virtual Machine from http://modern.ie. Once I have it stood up I'll test this again and report back with an update.

Comment: I still see the problem in W8.1 / IE11. Did you click on "edit jsbin" and then, each time, on "run with js" to refresh the bug ? Also IE11 is better, so the bug is harder to catch. You have to know it's here. (also saw it in VMs & Surface, so not specitic to my machine.)

Comment: @mddw I am not seeing it in IE11. Are you seeing it consistently, each time you run the demo?

Comment: Yes, each time I reboot it with "run with js". But it's hard to catch on IE11 + a good rig, the repaint occurs as soon as the div translate in viewport. It's slower and more visible on a surface.

Comment: @mddw I have a surface I can test with; I presume you're using a SurfaceRT, as the Pro is fairly powerful.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't replicate your bug, but I have a guess on what could be the cause of it.

Try disabling hardware acceleration in IE10/11 (Under Internet options > Advanced, should be something like Accelerated graphics > Disabling GPU and using software rendering — my windows is in portuguese, so I don't have the exact location), restart Windows (it might be a system-wide configuration).

Then try it again, if the problem persists, it might be a bug related to incompatibility between IE and your graphics card — that would explain why so many people could not replicate your bug (like me).

Some CSS features trigger hardware acceleration, that's why they're much more interesting than js animations — but some browsers/GPU combinations sometimes lag or only show the first and last steps of the animation.

Comment: I also had this problem on a Surface tablet, so it's not an hardware problem.